# Number Masking in Twillio India

Tags: proxy

**We trying to do number masking in Twillio (similar to Uber, Swiggy...) **

Our customer number/ partner phone number has to be masked by the twillio number when they try to talk each other

When I tried to test twillio proxy call between two Indian number I am not able to make a proxy call because the number we bought in Twillio was a USA number.

So trying to understand if twillio proxy call feature in Indian number If I going to buy a twillio Indian number

When I tried to test twillio proxy call between two Indian number I am not able to make a proxy call because the number we bought in Twillio was a USA number.

So trying to understand if twillio proxy call feature in Indian number If I going to buy a twillio Indian number